# Can the Kai earings(Potara Earings) be used again and again to keep fusing individuals?

Tags: dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-series

Supreme Kai and Kibito fused using the Kai Earrings. Can now Kibito Kai use the earrings again to fuse with another?

I searched for this and found no creditable source.

I know for a fact that the ear rings still work, since they were offered by Kibito Kai to Goku and Vegeta before the battle against Kid Buu. However they destroyed it. So could Kibito Kai use it to fuse again?

Edit: Accepted answer has added a somewhat relevant frame. It doesn't make it explicit but seems to indicate that fused individuals such as Elder kai, Kibito Kai and Vegeto can no longer fuse again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rou Kaioshin says that you can only fuse once. But the way it's worded it could mean that the person you once was can't fuse with another because you won't be yourself anymore. I.E. Goku can only fuse once because afterwards he won't be Goku anymore.

[image: raw panel]

> Rou Kaioshin: "Also, you can use the Potara only once in your lifetime!"
>
> Goku: "Oh... Did you use it with someone else too...?"

Chapter: 502 (DBZ 308), P1.4

^Above is the VIZ big translation. I have added the raw panel as well just in case you want the Japanese. I don't have a translation for it myself. Sorry.

Comment: Choosing to accept this answer for its only reference. It seems to indicate fused individuals like Kibito Kai, Elder Kai and Vegeto can't fuse again using the Potara earings.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **YES** and **NO**, it all depends on which Akira Toriyama wants them to be.

*Potara Fusion* is not just a fusion, it somewhat merge two beings into one,  sharing both memories. Unlike the *Fusion Dance*, even though they have fused into one being, but they still have both performers' conscious, that's why you hear 2 sounds overlapping when fused character is talking.

I saw this example on the wiki, it says:

> Have Goku and Vegeta fuse with Potara Earrings, then have Trunks and Goten do the same. Then, have Vegito remove one of his earring and have Trunken do the same, and they'll become Gogetenks. It's like how Supreme Kai and Kibito fused by removing their Potara Earrings. I don't think they've ever said what happens if a Potara fusion removes their earrings, so I assume it would work this way. By that logic, everyone in the DBZ universe could fuse into one ultimate being.

Despite the possibilities of using Potara earrings over and over again to create an ultimate strongest warrior, I think you would probably ***never*** see this multi-fused character ever in the DBZ universe, unless the writer is a 12 years old kid.

Comment: The wiki is wrong on the case that "They've never said what happens if a Potara fusion removes the earrings." Supreme Kai explicitly stated that the Potara fusion was permanent, meaning even after removing the earrings it would last.

Comment: The wiki is a tertiary source at best (i.e., not reliable or authoritative), so you're better off taking a bit more effort and referencing the source material than the wiki.