# Can 4 people fuse into 1 powerful person?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

Can Fusion AB (A fuses with B) and Fusion CD (C fuses with D) fuse again (AB fuses with CD) with something like Potara? Can it even be done?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no quad-fusion or fusion between 2 a already fused fighters. Similar to [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/32320/can-the-kai-earingspotara-earings-be-used-again-and-again-to-keep-fusing-indiv?rq=1), you essentially have to be your original self to fuse with another person.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! Nice to see a fellow Arqade member around these parts ;)

Comment: @Wondercricket ;) Hello friend, glad to be here! I'll be around these parts more and more I think